# How to add few condition to hasMany relationship?

Tags: activerecord, yii2, has-many

I have model

```
class Drug extends ActiveRecord
{

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getProblems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Problem::class, ['id' => 'problem_id'])
            ->via('consumptionRateProblems');
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getConsumptionRateProblems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ConsumptionRateProblem::class, ['consumption_rate_id' => 'id'])
            ->via('consumptionRates');
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getConsumptionRates()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ConsumptionRate::class, ['drug_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

I need to get Problems for some Drug, that connected via culture_id and drug_id in consumptionRates table.

When I use `andOnCondition` - i get error "Not unique table/alias: 'consumption_rate'"

```
 $drugs = Drug::find()
     ->joinWith(['consumptionRates' => function (ActiveQuery $query) use ($cultureId) {
         return $query->andOnCondition(['consumption_rate.culture_id' => $cultureId]);
     }])
     ->all();
```

How should I build my query for getting a result I need ?

Comment: explain the relation between your tables

Comment: Try this: `Drug::find()->joinWith(['consumptionRates'])->andWhere(['consumption_rate.culture_id' => $cultureId])->all();`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Serghiy Leonenco!

```
 $drugs = Drug::find()
    ->joinWith(['consumptionRates'])->andWhere(['consumption_rate.culture_id' => $cultureId])
->all();
```